# Can I overwrite the type of an S4 slot in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

If I have an S4 object like this:

```
obj1 <- setClass(
  "obj1",
  slots = c(
    x = "numeric",
    y = "numeric"
  )
)
```

Is there a way to make a second object that inherits from `obj1` but overwrites one of the data types of a slot? i.e.

```
obj2 <- setClass(
  "obj2",
  slots = c(
    x = "character"
  ),
  contains = "obj1"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to implement this would be to have both `obj1` and `obj2` inherit from a virtual class containing the common slots. This is particularly useful if you want to be able to call many of the same methods on both `obj1` and `obj2`.

Let's say we have the virtual class `obj0`:

```r
obj0 <- setClass(
  "obj0",
  slots = c(
    y = "numeric"
  ),
  contains = "VIRTUAL"
)
```

Then we can define the `obj1` and `obj2` classes with just the unique slots we want, while allowing them to inherit everything else from `obj0`

```r
obj1 <- setClass(
  "obj1",
  slots = c(
    x = "numeric"
  ),
  contains = "obj0"
)

obj2 <- setClass(
  "obj2",
  slots = c(
    x = "character"
  ),
  contains = "obj0"
)
```

Creating an instance of each object type, we get the desired result for `obj1` and `obj2`

```
obj1()
#> An object of class "obj1"
#> Slot "x":
#> numeric(0)
#> 
#> Slot "y":
#> numeric(0)
obj2()
#> An object of class "obj2"
#> Slot "x":
#> character(0)
#> 
#> Slot "y":
#> numeric(0)
```

And we don't need to worry about users trying to instantiate the incomplete `obj0` class because they are disallowed:

```r
obj0()
#> Error in new(structure("obj0", package = ".GlobalEnv"), ...): 
#>  trying to generate an object from a virtual class ("obj0")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of setClass says :

> The slots in a class definition will be the union of all the slots
> specified directly by slots and all the slots in all the contained
> classes. There can only be one slot with a given name. *A class may
> override the definition of a slot with a given name, **but only if the
> newly specified class is a subclass of the inherited one**. For
> example, if the contained class had a slot a with class "ANY", then a
> subclass could specify a with class "numeric", but if the original
> specification for the slot was class "character", the new call to
> setClass would generate an error.*